# FTB: Unleashed crashes on startup

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

It starts after I click Launch on the FTB launcher set on unleashed, and it goes to the Mojang screen, but once the console gets to the point where it usually stops and the Minecraft title screen comes on, it simply closes. The last two lines of the console are:

```
2014-03-09 21:25:29 [INFO] [STDOUT] Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
2014-03-09 21:25:29 [INFO] [STDOUT]     (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL. For more
information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
```

[This is the error log from the folder FTB resides in (it's named hs_err_pid4960.log). It's in link form because the log is extremely long.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14mKDqDSD0drFhRuaaDRsYhLUPGrL9FacfPRuTNiemEI/)

My computer has 32 bit Windows 7 and 2GB RAM. It won't run any other FTB pack, but all of them work on another computer that I don't have with me at the moment.

**EDIT:** The error from MinecraftLog.txt:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x67e82ce0, pid=4852, tid=5056
#
# JRE version: 6.0_14-b08
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.0-b16 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [OpenAL32.dll+0x32ce0]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Noah\Downloads\hs_err_pid4852.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: According to the log, the error is not within Java but native code.  So its quite possible its FTB itself or some other software.  If you could post some more info such as Java version, FTB version, etc, someone should be able to narrow down the problem.

Comment: My Java IS outdated, but I'm unable to update it as I am not an administrator on my computer. When the administrator attempts to update the java, as soon as the installer finishes it says that a Java update is available  (again) thus rendering the install useless. My FTB Launcher version is 1.3.5, I just downloaded it today.

Comment: 2GB ram isn't enough to even start up FTB anymore I don't think.

Comment: Within the Options menu of FTB it says that I have 32 bit java, and says that it won't be able to use more than 1.5 GB RAM for it. It has worked on 32 bit java on my other computer, using 1 gb ram.

Comment: are you using a texture pack? my wife's desktop runs out of memory and crashes FTB if she attemps to load it with a texture pack, due to her 32bit OS

Comment: i should add to the message that for my wife it runs fine without a texturepack, its the TP that pushes the machine over it's limit of memory

Comment: I'm not using a texture pack I'm just trying to run FTB Unleashed

Comment: Modded minecraft crashing is off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft support and we can only help vanilla minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with 32 Bit windows, and I've unfortunately figure this out the hard way, is that it physically cannot allocate enough RAM, to pre-load all the textures and item IDs and launch.

Unfortunately the only solution is to upgrade OS, which would require re-downloading everything, and getting the OS, or opening the mods folder and getting rid of mods with a lot of items that you may not use.